# How to read a zip file from a remote URL without extracting it

Tags: java

I am trying to directly read a  zip file  from a Remote URL 
I have tried this way

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Utils {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String ftpUrl = "http://wwwccc.zip";
        URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
        unpackArchive(url);
    }

    public static void unpackArchive(URL url) throws IOException {
        String ftpUrl = "http://www.vvvv.xip";
        File zipFile = new File(url.toString());
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("entry: " + entry.getName() + ", "
                    + entry.getSize());
            BufferedReader bufferedeReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(zip.getInputStream(entry)));
            String line = bufferedeReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = bufferedeReader.readLine();
            }
            bufferedeReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\www.nseindia.com\content\historical\EQUITIES\2015\NOV\cm03NOV2015bhav.csv.zip (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Utils.unpackArchive(Utils.java:30)
    at Utils.main(Utils.java:19)
```

Where as the URL of zip file is working fine when running from a browser .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` class is not designed to work with remote files. It only supports files that are available on a local file system. To open a stream on a remote file, you can use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Call [`getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) on an `HttpURLConnection` instance to get an input stream that you can process further.

Example:

```
String url= "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/NOV/cm03NOV2015bhav.csv.zip";
InputStream is = new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
```

Comment: In the code example, it should be `HttpURLConnection` with capital ´URL´

Comment: Just noted that `HttpURLConnection` is abstract, meaning it cannot be instantiated just like this.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen, right. I updated my answer. Also Mike Nakis answer is obviously a better one than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Reading Zip file stored on remote Location.Just need to change your remote location zip file Details in below code base.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

  public class ReadZipFileFromRemote{
        public static void main(String args[]){
           String url="https://test-po.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/coding/76/55/14/1/1587736321256.zip";
           String content=readZipFileFromRemote(url);
           System.out.println(content);  
        }  

        public String readZipFileFromRemote(String remoteFileUrl) {        

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         try {
             URL url = new URL(remoteFileUrl);
             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
             ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(in);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             ZipEntry entry;
             while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                  int read;
                 while ((read = stream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                      sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
                }
            }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above has worked for me.

What ***did*** work like a charm, is this:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL( urlString ).openStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the line

```
File zipFile = new File(url.toString());
```

you are trying to create a file named like the URL which contains characters that are not allowed.

The file should be named simpler like

```
File zipFile = new File("zipfile.csv.zip");
```

The compiler is telling you that aswell:

***(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)***

I am sure this is why you are getting the error. But i'm not certain about the rest of the code.

Comment: i did this way    File zipFile = new File("cm03NOV2015bhav.csv.zip"); its ot working for me .  zipfile.csv.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: The file name can be whatever you feel like. You could also Trim the URL and have only the file name in the link be the file name on your server.

Answer (score -3):

you cant create file from url like that
try this :

> URL ftpUrl = new URL("http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES>/2015/NOV/cm03NOV2015bhav.csv.zip");
>
> File zipFile = new File("some location on your local drive");
>
> FileUtils.copyURLToFile(ftpUrl, zipFile);
>
> ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);